# Leadtools bitmap to OpenCV Mat and back

Tags: opencv, leadtools-sdk

I have a LeadTools `Bitmap` that I need to convert to OpenCV's `Mat` to do some processing on, and then convert it back to LeadTools `Bitmap`. What is the best way to do this?

I know OpenCV can read files and write them back, but that is not an option for me for many reasons that are not worth mentioning here

I'm using C++, but samples in any programming languages are appreciated.

Comment: use the appropriate constructor of cv::Mat. there are constructors that take [element type, width, height, and data pointer](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d3/d63/classcv_1_1Mat.html#a51615ebf17a64c968df0bf49b4de6a3a). leadtools, being a commercial thing, and three orders of magnitude less known than opencv, should have documentation on how to interface with the rest of the world.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for using the LEADTOOLS SDK. Can you please send an email to support@leadtools.com with the following information:

- What version of the LEADTOOLS SDK are you using?
- Some sample images that you are wanting to convert

To see a full list of our technical support options, please visit this link: https://www.leadtools.com/support/supportoptions

Technical support is provided free to all registered LEADTOOLS customers and includes email and live chat.